# Node JS gets gets stuck after Error: ENOENT

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

My application uses node.js (10.28) and express (3.4.7) the server.js is like this

```
var express = require('express'),
config = require('./services/resource/config.js'),
routeprocess = require('./services/routeprocess/routeprocess.js'),
socketevent = require('./socketevent'),
cluster = require('cluster'),
RedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis')
redis  = require('socket.io/node_modules/redis')
numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
logger = require('./services/logger/logger.js');
var channels=['XXXXXX','YYYYYY','ZZZZZZZZZZ'];

app = express();
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(app.router);

app.use(function(req, res){
   res.sendfile(__dirname + '/web/'+ req.url );
});

app.use(function(err,req,res,next) {
    console.log(err);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/web/'+ 'index.html' );
});

// couple of REST Calls
app.all('/rest/summary/:code?', function (req, res) {        
   routeprocess.onStoreGraphSummary(req, res, req.params.storeCode);
});

app.all('/rest/offerdetails/:offerNos?', function (req, res) {      
   routeprocess.onOfferDetails(req, res, req.params.offerNos);
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/web',{ maxAge: 2592000000 }));
// Below this we have the forking / redisstore , socket etc
```

The issue is that once the server starts and runs for a few minutes , we start getting a lot of Error: ENOENT

something like this

```
Error: ENOENT, stat '/home/auto/xxxx/appp/4Jun/8180/web//dashsummary'
[2014-06-04 04:31:52.130] [INFO] console - { [Error: ENOENT, stat '/home/auto/xxxx/appp/4Jun/8180/web//dashsummary']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/auto/xxxx/appp/4Jun/8180/web//dashsummary',
  status: 404 }
```

/dashsummary is a valid link which is mentioned in my AngularJS application in my routeprovider

```
 $routeProvider
    .when('/dashsummary', {
        controller: 'DashController',
        templateUrl: 'view/modules/dashsummary.html'
    })
```

These Error: ENOENT happen so many times and I feel the NodeJS server is completely stuck at this

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Why are there two slashes in your URL before dashsummary? /web//dashsummary

Answer (score 1):

If this line is supposed to be serving up that URL, try removing the trailing "/"

```
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/web/'+ req.url );
```

to

```
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/web'+ req.url );
```

Comment: Sorry for being late .. but trying that would not help as the template URL is given as view/modules/dashsummary.html and that what requires the / at frongt

Comment: But you have two slashes in the logged URL, which is an invalid URL. Look at the path listed in the error message you posted.